# How to align the border as center inside the popup control

Tags: windows-runtime

I am trying to align the border to the center of the popup. But it aligns only at the top left corner. can anyone suggest how to align the border to the center of the popup control.

```
 <Grid Name="MainGrid" Background="Green">
    <Popup Name="mainpopup" IsOpen="True"  >
            <Border Name="MainBorder" Background="LightBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Width="1300">

            </Border>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

**Additional Details:** In My application (winrt application) the border height is set as Auto it takes the height according to its contents height.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show a complete example, which do you use and what you have is located in content of `Border`?

Comment: I just have few stack panel and inside I have texboxes and some textblock and set visibility to the stackpanels according to my actions

Comment: For `StackPanel` in Border setting `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` and `VerticalAlignment="Center"`?

Comment: Sorry its not working the border itself is not aligned, then how come with stackpanel

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, your screen resolution should be 1366X768 which makes your border appear left aligned.  Check with minimizing the width and update if its getting center aligned.

Comment: No its again appeared in the top left corner

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by handling popup opened event and sets the vertical offset for the popup as shown below.

```
var bound = Window.Current.Bounds;
        var center = (bound.Height / 2) - (poupChildBorder.ActualHeight / 2);
        Mypopup.VerticalOffset = center;
```

Comment: nice workaround inside the border some dynamic contents are there so some of the times I m getting border actualHeight as 0.0.